# Angular 1.2.16, isolated scope, parent function and ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm stumped with a rather simple issue with Angular (as I think it is simple). Sometimes Angular make me feel dumb, because it can't be possible I'm doing something terrible wrong.

Take this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/BmM9C5zjDAIfGTVzkU29?p=preview

HTML:

```html
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ASDF">
    <div fb-login="doh" ng-click="exec()">CLICKY (should execute parent scope function but doesnt)</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ASDF', function($scope){
   $scope.doh = function(d){
      alert(d);
   }
})
.directive('fbLogin', function(){
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     replace: false,
     scope: {
       done: '&fbLogin'
     },
     link: function(scope){
       scope.exec = function(){
         scope.done()('asdf');
       };
     }
   }
});
```

What's going on in here?

Comment: I don't see an exec function on the parent scope (inside the ASDF controller).

Comment: it's not an `exec` function in the parent controller, it's the `doh` function (passed in the isolated scope). but `exec()` isn't executing, therefore not executing the parent function

Comment: Don't see a point to have `ng-click="exec()"` as an attribute to the element since `exec` is something in the directive itself and why should we give it to the out side. Instead you could do `element.click(function(){ scope.done()('asdf'); })` in th edirective ?

Comment: it's a dumbed version of my problem, the real app have a really complicated strutucture with many other directives and forms. I don't ever use ng-click without namespaces and controller functions in my real app

Comment: The ng-click is going to look for exec on the scope of the ASDF controller.  I believe the isolated scope only applies to the fb-login directive.

Comment: yes, that's why I'm using an isolated scope, the `exec()` should be from the isolated scope only, but it's not executing

Comment: this behavior used to work "pre" 1.2, not anymore, see my own answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isolate scope in 1.2 versions are trully isolate (see https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/909cabd36d779598763cc358979ecd85bb40d4d7)

> **fix($compile): make isolate scope truly isolate**
>
> Fixes issue with isolate scope leaking all over the place into other
>   directives on the same element.
>
> Isolate scope is now available only to the isolate directive that
>   requested it and its template.
>
> A non-isolate directive should not get the isolate scope of an isolate
>   directive on the same element, instead they will receive the original
>   scope (which is the parent scope of the newly created isolate scope).
>
> Paired with Tobias.
>
> **BREAKING CHANGE:** Directives without isolate scope do not get the
>   isolate scope from an isolate directive on the same element. If your
>   code depends on this behavior (non-isolate directive needs to access
>   state from within the isolate scope), change the isolate directive to
>   use scope locals to pass these explicitly.
>
> *// before*
>
> .directive('ngIsolate', function() {   return {
>       scope: {},
>       template: '{{value}}'   }; });
>
> *// after*
>
> .directive('ngIsolate', function() {   return {
>       scope: {value: '=ngModel'},
>       template: '{{value}}   }; });

Then only way it works now is through a template / templateUrl (using transclude in this case, so I don't need to recreate it):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ASDF', function($scope){
   $scope.doh = function(d){
     alert(d);
  }
})
.directive('fbLogin', function(){
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     replace: false,
     scope: {
       done: '&fbLogin'
     },
     transclude: true,
     template: '<div ng-transclude ng-click="exec()"></div>',
     link: function(scope){         
       scope.exec = function(){
         scope.done()('asdf');
       };
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: ty, you've saved me tons of time

Answer (score 1):

Because the ng-click is only going to have access to the parent scope, it is trying to execute exec on the scope of the ASDF controller.

I believe this will give you the behavior you want:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ASDF">
    <div fb-login="doh">CLICKY (should execute parent scope function but doesnt)</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ASDF', function($scope){
   $scope.doh = function(d){
      alert(d);
   }
})
.directive('fbLogin', function(){
   return {
     restrict: 'A',
     replace: false,
     scope: {
       done: '&fbLogin'
     },
     link: function(scope, element){
       element.on("click", function () { scope.done()('asdf') });
     }
   }
});
```